# Build difference between current and previous year from based on key column

Tags: dataframe

I got the following df:

```
Name   Year  [Columns which should stay like that]  V2  C2   KeyC
A      2001       ...                               4   7    NA
A      2002       ...                               2   0.5   1
A      2003       ...                               4   0.2   0
A      2005       ...                               3   0.3   NA
B      2004       ...                               0   0.4   NA
B      2006       ...                               1   7     NA
B      2007       ...                               2   0.6   1
C      2002       ....                              4     4    NA
```

So the idea is the following. I have a column KeyC which contains a Non-Na-Value if the observation from my column Name has in the previous row the previous year. For example: For A: Row 2 contains the year 2002. Check if there is the previous year in row 1. Yes it is, as row 1 contains 2001.

What I want to do now is that I want to build the difference from the observations from the columns V2 and C2 by using the value from the current year minus the value from the previous year divided by the value from the previous year. Then I want to put that calculated value in the same row from the current year. So basically where in my keycolum there is a non-na-value.

Is there a way of doing this? :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat%>%
   group_by(Name)%>%
   mutate(i=c(0,diff(Year))==1,
         V2= ifelse(i,(V2-lag(V2))/lag(V2),V2),
         C2= ifelse(i,(C2-lag(C2))/lag(C2),C2),
         i=NULL)
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name   Year X.Columns.which.should.stay.like.that.     V2     C2  KeyC
  <fct> <int> <fct>                                   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 A      2001 ...                                     4.00   7.00     NA
2 A      2002 ...                                    -0.500 -0.929     1
3 A      2003 ...                                     1.00  -0.600     0
4 A      2005 ...                                     3.00   0.300    NA
5 B      2004 ...                                     0.     0.400    NA
6 B      2006 ...                                     1.00   7.00     NA
7 B      2007 ...                                     1.00  -0.914     1
8 C      2002 ....                                    4.00   4.00     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.table::fread(
  "Name   Year    V2  C2   KeyC
  A      2001                                      4   7    NA
  A      2002                                      2   0.5   1
  A      2003                                      4   0.2   0
  A      2005                                      3   0.3   NA
  B      2004                                      0   0.4   NA
  B      2006                                      1   7     NA
  B      2007                                      2   0.6   1
  C      2002                                      4     4    NA"
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V2, C2),
            ~ if_else(is.na(df$KeyC), as.double(.x),(.x - lag(.x)) / lag(.x)))

  Name Year   V2         C2 KeyC
1    A 2001  4.0  7.0000000   NA
2    A 2002 -0.5 -0.9285714    1
3    A 2003  1.0 -0.6000000    0
4    A 2005  3.0  0.3000000   NA
5    B 2004  0.0  0.4000000   NA
6    B 2006  1.0  7.0000000   NA
7    B 2007  1.0 -0.9142857    1
8    C 2002  4.0  4.0000000   NA
```

You can add additional variables to the `vars()` clause if you like

Comment: Just as a note: `KeyC`, will need to be spot on. @Onyambu's answer implements a check for both `Name` groups and subsequent years - which is a nice touch. Perhaps a combination of his answer with the `mutate_at` call will allow you to scale the solution to more variables more easily.